# Can you access the epoll interest list (a.k.a. interest set) directly?

Tags: c, linux, epoll

I'm new to epoll.  The man page for epoll mentions an interest list (a.k.a. epoll set), which is a superset of the ready set.  If you want to modify the interest list by adding new epoll events, deleting old epoll events, or modifying existing epoll events, it seems like you can use `epoll_ctl()`.  If you want to read the current ready set, it seems like you can use `epoll_wait()`.  Is there a way to access the interest list?  I'm looking for something that would behave similar to `epoll_wait()` in that it would give you a list of all epoll events.

Context:

My systems class is having us use epoll to I/O multiplex, and they're going to use valgrind to check for leaks.  I use the `epoll_event.data.ptr` field to point to a struct I've malloc'd on the heap.  I need to free all this when the program is sent a signal to terminate.  I recognize I could create a list of active epoll_events on my side, but I just want to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel before I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't reinventing the wheel. Keeping track in your own code of all the connections your code is handling is the right way to do it.